# What is ?s term used for in updating SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in android development. 
I have a question. what is **?s** term used for in explanation below? i got it from the documentation of android developer.

public int update (String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

Added in API level 1
Convenience method for updating rows in the database.

Parameters
table   the table to update in
values  a map from column names to new column values. null is a valid value that will be translated to NULL.
whereClause the optional WHERE clause to apply when updating. Passing null will update all rows.
whereArgs   You may include **?s** in the where clause, which will be replaced by the values from whereArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.
Returns
the number of rows affected

Answer (score 2):

Basically its a variable to be filled in later.  You should use these everywhere that data is coming from a user, a file, or anything else not hardcoded into the app.  Why?  Because it prevents security problems due to SQL injection.  The variables cannot themselves be SQL, and will not be parsed as SQL by the database.  So if all variables sent from users to the db are bind variables you remove that entire class of security issues from the app.

Answer (score 1):

A [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) supports a mechanism called [bind variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). For example,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?
```

In the above query, there is a single bind parameter for an id. You might use it (to get a row where `id` is `100`) with something like

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    ps.setInt(1, 100);
    try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {

        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each ? corresponds, in order, to an index of the sql arguments passed in the method's last `String[] whereArgs` parameter

```
public int update (table, values, "age > ? AND age < ?", new String[] { "18", "25"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation meant literally using '?' in the whereClause statement. Simple example:

```
rawQuery("select * from todo where _id = ?", new String[] { id });
```

From the above statement, during execution, the ? will be replaced by the value of variable id.

This mechanism helps prevent SQL Injection.